# comparing 2 rows + grouping Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I do this? I am lost.

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ ITEM   ║ PRICE    ║ DATE     ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ Dollar ║       60 ║ 1.3.2016 ║
║ Dollar ║       50 ║ 2.3.2016 ║
║ Bound  ║      100 ║ 1.3.2016 ║
║ Bound  ║      110 ║ 2.3.2016 ║
║ Euro   ║      600 ║ 1.3.2016 ║
║ Euro   ║      580 ║ 3.3.2016 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Output should display one item from each type with last price and price difference from previous row

```
╔════════╦══════════╦════════════════════════╗
║ ITEM   ║ PRICE    ║ DATE     ║ Differnece  ║
╠════════╬══════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ Dollar ║       50 ║ 2.3.2016 ║   -10       ║
║ Bound  ║      110 ║ 2.3.2016 ║    10       ║
║ Euro   ║      580 ║ 3.3.2016 ║   -20       ║
╚════════╩══════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Sorry, you can see it now

Comment: What have you tried so far? If the answer is nothing other than to think "I'm lost" then you need to hire a programmer to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name as 'Item',
       price as 'Price',
       (select max(date) from table where name like '%dollar%') as 'Date',
       (select top 1 price from table where name like '%dollar%') - (select top 1 price from table where id< (select max(id) from table where name like '%dollar%')and name like '%dollar%' order by id desc) as 'difference'
       from table where name like '%dollar%'
union all --now just repeat the code above and switch the like as you want
select name as 'Item',
       price as 'Price',
       (select max(date) from table where name like '%bound%') as 'Date',
       (select top 1 price from table where name like '%bound%') - (select top 1 price from table where id< (select max(id) from table where name like '%bound%')and name like '%bound%' order by id desc) as 'difference'
       from table where name like '%bound%'
```

Comment: This will be a slow query xD, if you want something fast hire a programmer